# Flutter Transform doesn't restict to parent size

Tags: flutter, frontend, flutter-layout, transform, translate

I have the problem that I want to transform a image, but it only should be shown inside the parent container. The parts of the image that are outside of the parent container should be hided.

To display and transform the photos I have this code:

```
new Column(
    children: [
        Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Center(
                child: Transform(
                    transform: Matrix4(
                        2,0,0,0,
                        0,2,0,0,
                        0,0,1,0,
                        1,1,1,1,
                    )..translate(x, y, z),
                    alignment: FractionalOffset.topCenter,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                        onPanUpdate: (details) {
                            setState(() {
                                y = y + details.delta.dy;
                                x = x + details.delta.dx;
                            });
                        },
                        child: Image.file(
                            widget.takenImage
                        )
                    ),
                )
            ),
        ),
        Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Center(...)
        ),
    ],
)
```

As you can see on the photos: the top image is like it should be. But after transformig the photo, it is like the secons screenshot. But it only should be displayed inside its container. Does anyone have a solution for that?

[Two containers - top and bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7268g.png)

[Two containers - after transform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiBVZ.png)

Comment: use `ClipRect` then - the official docs say: *"A widget that clips its child using a rectangle.

By default, ClipRect prevents its child from painting outside its bounds, but the size and location of the clip rect can be customized using a custom clipper."*

Comment: sure, your welcome